# cannot import new database from pg_dump, out of memory. psql cloned_db < db_backup.sql

Tags: database, postgresql

made a backup of a remote database by the following

```
pg_dump dbname | gzip > filename.gz
```

made a new database that i want to import it to

```
CREATE DATABASE new_clone;
```

tried importing into new database by the following command:

```
gunzip -c /path/to/backup/filename.sql.gz | psql new_clone
```

working, imported parts of the database, but ran into error

```
out of memory
```

no other information... most tables and schemas have appeared, but I cannot get past this problem.

ive tried doing a simple

```
pg_dump dbname > filename
```

and a

```
psql dbname < infile
```

tried without compression, and it fails as well. 
my guess is that a blob inside the database is too large? is there a way to skip the blobs that cause errors?

database size is 10GB uncompressed, 2.2GB compressed. i have 135GB free disk space, and 32GB ram. running ubuntu 14.04, postgres v 9.6.2

appreciate any help at all. thanks.

Comment: First, try to find out where the OOM comes from. If from the database server, it should be in the log file. Try to raise operating system memory limits and see if you can get rid of it. To narrow down where the problem happens, use the `-e` option of `psql` so that you can see the queries as they are executed; that way you can figure out where the problem happens.

Comment: it might have completed actually. i used the -e option, and i see the following:

    --
    -- PostgreSQL database dump complete
    --

    ERROR:  out of memory
    DETAIL:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 0 bytes by      2120117492 more bytes.

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL log file of the server where you import. There you should see which statement caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue. After little digging I found that is not psql issue, but sdin: after change `COPY ... FROM stdin` to `COPY ... from '/path/to/file/with.dump'` all became fine. So when you try feed psql through stdin, IMHO, OS, not psql, trying load all dump into memory, and, as dump bigger, than memory process can have, you got error.

PS I'm sorry for my bad English, it is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

To improve k.o. answer, `psql --no-readline` could be used to avoid stdin(readline) OOM issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. I am working on ubuntu 20.04 and postgres version is 12. You should try reading the first line of the error. The main error is written on the first line. In my case, postgis-scripts were missing. As a result, I was getting the OOM error. To fix it, run:

```
sudo apt-get install postgis postgresql-12-postgis-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a 30GB database dump, and splitting the file up works well for me.

To back it up do a dump of the file and, pipe it through `split`

```
pg_dump dbname | split -b 1000m - backup.dump
```

Then restore it using a pipe from `cat`

```
createdb dbname
cat backup.dump* | psql dbname
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/backup.html#BACKUP-DUMP-LARGE